# MySQL: query to create a row for every primary key in parent row

Tags: mysql, sql

This can easily be scripted, but I would like to learn how to do it in just pure SQL. I have a `users` table. In the `users` table, `id` is the primary key. Now imagine I have a new table called `foos`. Each user can have one foo. I'd like to be able to create a row (doesn't matter if data is the same right now) for every user I have in the `users` table into the table `foos`. `foos` just has just two columns, `user_id`,`name`.

What's the best way to loop through users and create an accompanying row in `foos` for each user where `user_id` is the user.id and name is any random string.

Comment: So, you just want to copy the `user.id`? Or the `user.name` too? Because creating random strings is not trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into foo (user_id, name)
select id, SomeStringInUserThatDoesntMatter 
from users
```

OR

```
insert into foo (user_id, name)
select id, 'This fixed string'
from users
```

OR (with a little bit of fun)

```
insert into foo (user_id, name)
select id, '4'
from users
```

since,

[image: RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number.]

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it goes something like this:

```
insert into if not exists foo (user_id, name)
select user_id, "any random stuff" from users;
```

You need to watch out that running it twice will not run into errors, so we need the "if not exists" clause.

Comment: +1 for taking rerunability (no, I'm not sure that's a real word either) into consideration.